# How to pass in variable when using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

Normally I could use scope to pass the variable from controller to view. But when I use ng-include to include some html snippet, how to pass in the variables?

For example, I write some header.html and use ng-include to add this to the main page?

Comment: Does your "html snippet" have its own controller?

Comment: The "included" html will inherit scope from the main view/controller.  So are you trying access variables from the main to the included or vise versa?

Comment: @jbrown, no its own controller

Comment: How to specify the main view/controller?

Comment: I can share an example, via plunker, but I need more info.  Specifically, I need an answer to my question "So are you trying access variables from the main to the included or vise versa?"

Comment: from main to he included

Comment: Ok, give me a minute and I'll have a plunker for you

Comment: Ok, check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/8SuMEyZBRvsK2z6ut6yC?p=preview  Let me know if it requires any explanation.